# split up tables according to keywords

Tags: excel

I can download excel exports of my monthly transactions from my bank. It gives me a table with the following columns:

**[date][account number][amount][debit/credit][account name][code][description]**

I want to create a file splits this up into different tables according to certain keywords such as:

- Put all transactions where the description contains an item from a list of keywords into category x (e.g: Put all transactions where the description contains "spotify" or "netflix" into the table for subscriptions.)
- Put all transactions that don't match any criteria into miscellaneous table.
- Add up all items per table per month.

I can't find out which functions to use to achieve this. The filter function seems about right but too limited. Any ideas?

Comment: 1.  Why do you believe the FILTER() function to be too limited? 2.  VBA would probably be best.

Comment: use power query [see this article](https://exceleratorbi.com.au/self-referencing-tables-power-query/)